# Capybara Cucumber matchers

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I've been asked by a colleague to help with his problem but I too, am becoming stuck on it.

He wants to find a clickable element by the text on it from a list he's got.

The list contains:

```
list = [ 'cat : B',
         'cat : B1',
         'cat : BE'
       ]
```

When he iterates over the list, the first iteration clicks on `cat : B` as expected. The next iteration also clicks on `cat : B` instead of `B1`.

the code used is:

```
list.each do |cat_item|
find('li.category', text: cat_item, :match => :prefer_exact).click
```

It's looks as though Capybara is only matching as far as the first B and thinking it's found the element, instead of matching to B1 or BE.

Is there a way around this? I've tried several ways

Answer (score 0):

The :prefer_exact match option has no effect on the :text option ( neither does `exact: true` - they only affects selectors that use the `XPath.is` method - selectors like :field, :label, :button, etc which take a string to potentially match against label text ).  To do exact matching with the :text option you need to pass a Regexp.  That said, it shouldn't be matching just B when you pass B1, have you printed out the text of the found elements to confirm which elements it's actually finding, and that it's not an issue with your click handler?